# How to define double data type in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

For integers, I use

```
userId:
  type: integer
  format: int32
```

But what if I want to assign the double type?

I tried looking through Swagger documentation but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: *"I tried looking through Swagger documentation but couldn't find the answer"* FYI this is explained in the [Data Types](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#data-types) section of the OpenAPI Specification and also in https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/.

Answer (score 14):

We can write as

```
userId:
    type: number
    format: double
```